# Druid resting in animal form

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, wild-shape

Can a druid rest in his animal form so he can then just keep shifting into animal form? Say turn into a cat, nap for an hour turn into a cat rest for an hour and so on to stay in disguise for a spy mission?